# Certain message values always undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Content script message send:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    action: 'Action',
    actType: 'Type',
    value: 1
  });
...
```

In the function below, I'm able to get the value of request.action and request.value, but request.actType always returns undefined. How can I get the value of actType?

```
//Background script

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
...
} else if (request.action == 'GainXP') {
    chrome.storage.sync.get('X', function(result) {
      addType(String(request.actType));
      var x = parseInt(result.X);
      x += parseInt(request.value);
      chrome.storage.sync.set({'X': x}, function() {
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
          action: 'CheckX'
        });
      });
    });
  }
...
function addType(x) {
  if (typeof x === undefined) {
    return;
  } else {
    if (x == "Type1") {
      chrome.storage.sync.get('type1count', function(result) {
        var newtypes = parseInt(result.type1count) + 1;
        chrome.storage.sync.set({'type1count': newtypes}, function() {});
        return;
      });
    }
```

Edit: Added more of the relevant code in order to help understand the context of the problem. Additionally, if I insert alerts before the addType call and after the addType call, only the first alert is executed.

Comment: It's quite clear that code you presented is insufficient to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Added significantly more relevant code. There are no other elements relevant to the message attribute in question so any instances of ellipses is merely an omission of similar message value checks.

Comment: Your problem may be in hitting sync storage rate limits - they are quite small. Then your operations may fail. Try the same code with all sync replaced by local.

Comment: Unfortunately the problem persists when all instances of sync are replaced by local

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. My manifest was referencing an older minified content script that didn't correctly set the actType message values. Following that I had to reorder my storage callbacks and all the relevant data is being updated with chrome.storage.sync.